# Nose @with_test not working

Tags: python-2.7, nose, nosetests, python-unittest

I have a situation where for some of the tests, I require to use different setup method than I have defined for all, And for this I though to use @with_setup decorator of nose.

However this doesn't seem to be working.

code:

```
import unittest
from nose.tools.nontrivial import with_setup
__author__ = 'gaurang_shah1'

class Demo(unittest.TestCase):

    def setup_func(self):
        print "setup_func"

    def teardown_func(self):
        print "teardown function"

    def setUp(self):
        print "setup"

    @with_setup(setup_func, teardown_func)
    def test_setup(self):
        print "test setup"
```

I am expecting following output, 
setup_func 
test setup
teardown_func

However I am getting following output, is there anything wrong I am doing here. 
setup
test setup

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing a unittest subclass, and as such it will always use unittest.setUp and tearDown methods for the test. As described in the [documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html):

> Note that with_setup is useful only for test functions, **not for test
>   methods** or inside of **TestCase** subclasses.

If you want to use @with_setup, drop the class all together:

```
from nose.tools.nontrivial import with_setup

def setup_func():
    print "setup_func"

def teardown_func():
    print "teardown function"

@with_setup(setup_func, teardown_func)
def test_something():
    print "test"
```

Or better yet, create another unittest class that does your custom setUp function.

Comment: You can just call your `setup_func()` from a test method on startup if you are so inclined.